# How do I change the order of attachments in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

How do I change the order of attachments in Gmail, when I compose a new email?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to do that once uploaded. You need to upload attachments one at a time in the order you want them.

Answer (score 3):

Currently you cannot reorder them, and there is actually no need to reorder them. When your recipient downloads the attachments, the OS file manager will sort them accordingly.

However, if you do wish to make it ordered presentable you have you upload them in your sorted order, i.e., the top one first.